# Scatter Plot of predicted vs actual value with regression curve

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to use scatter plots with regression curves using the following code. I am using different algorithms like Linear regression, SVM and Gaussian Process etc. I have tried different options for plotting the data mentioned below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor


df=pd.read_excel(coded.xlsx)
dfnew=df[['FL','FW','TL','LL','KH']]

Y = df['KH']
X = df[['FL']]

X=X.values.reshape(len(X),1)
Y=Y.values.reshape(len(Y),1)

# Split the data into training/testing sets
X_train = X[:-270]
X_test = X[-270:]

# Split the targets into training/testing sets
Y_train = Y[:-270]
Y_test = Y[-270:]


#regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
#regressor.fit(X_train, np.ravel(Y_train))
#training the algorithm

regressor = GaussianProcessRegressor(random_state=42)
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

mse = np.sum((y_pred - Y_test)**2)


# root mean squared error
# m is the number of training examples
rmse = np.sqrt(mse/270)
print(rmse)

#X_grid = np.arange(min(X), max(X), 0.01) #this step required because data is feature scaled.
#X_grid = np.arange(0, 15, 0.01) #this step required because data is feature scaled.

#X_grid = X_grid.reshape((len(X_grid), 1))
#plt.scatter(X, Y, color = 'red')
print('size of Y_train = {0}'.format(Y_train.size))
print('size of y_pred = {0}'.format(y_pred.size))

#plt.scatter(Y_train, y_pred, color = 'red')
#plt.plot(X_grid, regressor.predict(X_grid), color = 'blue')
#plt.title('GPR')
#plt.xlabel('Measured')
#plt.ylabel('Predicted')
#plt.show()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 6))
plt.plot(X[:, 0], Y_train, marker='o', color='black', linewidth=0)
plt.plot(X[:, 0], y_pred, marker='x', color='steelblue')
plt.suptitle("$GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=RBF)$ [default]", fontsize=20)
plt.axis('off')
pass
```

But I am getting error like:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (540,) and (270, 1)

What is the possible solution?

Comment: Its easier to help you, when you gives us a bit of context (data). From the code I'd guess you should use either X and Y oder X_train and Y_train. From X you should just use the column of interest, e.g. `X['some_var_name']`

Comment: It's kind of difficult to understand what the real problem is with so much commented out code. For future reference, please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks Bill for your reply, however, commented code is just a different option that I have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code splits `X` and `Y` into training/testing sets, but then tries to plot a column from all of `X` with `Y_train` and `y_pred`, which have only half as many values as `X`. Try creating plots with `X_train` and `X_test` instead.

Comment: On the x-axis, I want training data and on the y-axis, I want predicted values. The size of both is the same i.e. 270.

Comment: @Gill On this line, you're using `X` instead of `X_train`: `plt.plot(X[:, 0], Y_train, marker='o', color='black', linewidth=0)`